# Error: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: ros-kinetic, ubuntu, rospy, rosrun, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to run the following node using rosrun, to send data through my serial port and I get the error:

```
/opt/ros/kinetic/bin/rosrun: /home/spyros/catkin_ws/src/usb_rs232/scripts/serial_connection.py: /opt/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
/opt/ros/kinetic/bin/rosrun: line 109: /home/spyros/catkin_ws/src/usb_rs232/scripts/serial_connection.py: Success
```

Also, when I compile the code with `catkin_make`, my node isn't on the list of: `Built target [my_node]`

The first version of the code (outside ROS-only python script) works fine. I think the problem has to be in the modification of the code, to run it as a ROS node.

Do you have any possible solution, or a hint of what might be the problem here?
I am new to ROS.
I use Ubuntu 16.04, ROS kinetic, Python 2.7

Thanks in advance!

```
#!/opt/bin/python
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
import serial
import time
from std_msgs.msg import String
def serial_connection():
    rospy.init_node('serial_connection', anonymous = True)
    rate = rospy.Rate(10)
    syxnotita = 0
    euros = 0
    mesi_gwnia = 0
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        data = [syxnotita, euros, mesi_gwnia]
        ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600)
        print (ser.name)
        time.sleep(2)
        while ser.isOpen():
            print ("Port Open")
            for i in range(5):
                print ('Hola!')
                ser.write("Hola!\n")
                time.sleep(1)
                rate.sleep()
        ser.close()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        serial_connection()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

---

Edit: The output is:

```
ls: cannot access '/opt/bin/python': No such file or directory
```

I used the same interpreter (`#!/opt/bin/python`) when I run the python script (outside ROS) from my terminal.  Then I added the line `#!/opt/bin/env python` following the steps of the tutorial for python subscriber node.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/306486/error:-bad-interpreter:-no-such-file-or-directory/) by [Spyros](https://answers.ros.org/users/35598/spyros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2018-10-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> /opt/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
> ```

Do you have a `python` binary in `/opt/bin`? What is the output of `ls -al /opt/bin/python`?

If not, why do you specify that as the interpreter to be used for this file?

---

Edit:

> The output is: ls: cannot access '/opt/bin/python': No such file or directory

Then it would appear there is no interpreter (or at least: no binary) there and you cannot specify it as the one to use for this file.

> I used the same interpreter (`#!/opt/bin/python`) when I run the python script (outside ROS) from my terminal.

I'm not saying you're lying, but I would find that really strange: ROS does nothing special here. It certainly doesn't change any of your Python interpreters or where they are located.

If there is no file at `/opt/bin/python`, then you cannot specify it as the interpreter to use for that file. With or without ROS.

> Then I added the line `#!/opt/bin/env python` following the steps of the tutorial for python subscriber node.

I believe you mean: `#!/usr/bin/env python`: that makes more sense, as `/usr/bin/env` will figure out which `python` binary to use based on your current settings.

Suggestion: remove `#!/opt/bin/python` from your file.

---

Edit 2:

> Reinstalletion worked ok, but after:
>
> ```
> /usr/bin/env python -c 'import yaml'
> ```
>
> I get:
>
> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
> ImportError: No module named yaml
> ```
>
> which python gave me:
>
> ```
> /usr/local/bin/python
> ```
>
> Without restarting laptop or terminal.

Now we're getting somewhere.

You *do* have a non-system-default Python interpreter on your system (it is a Python `2.7.15`, while the normal Python version for Ubuntu 16.04 is actually `2.7.12`) and it is taking precedence over the Ubuntu provided `python`.

The `python-yaml` Debian package only installs the `yaml` module for the system-default Python interpreter, so it makes sense that your custom Python interpreter cannot find it.

I don't know why you have that non-default Python in `/usr/local/bin`, but you'll either have to remove it or make sure that *all* modules required for ROS are also installed for the custom Python.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-10-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Spyros](https://answers.ros.org/users/35598/spyros/) on 2018-10-23**:
I removed that line and I run it again. I got the error:

```
ImportError: No module named yaml
```

My node was not at the Built list after I run catkin_make again.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-10-23**:
Do you have Anaconda or some other alternative Python interpreter installed?

What is the output of `dpkg -l | grep python-yaml`?

**Comment by [Spyros](https://answers.ros.org/users/35598/spyros/) on 2018-10-23**:
The output is:

```
ii  python-yaml                                  3.11-3build1                                          amd64        YAML parser and emitter for Python
```

No, I don't thing I have Anaconda or other Python interpreter.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-10-23**:
Ok. What is the output of `/usr/bin/env python --version` and `/usr/bin/env python -c 'import yaml'`?

**Comment by [Spyros](https://answers.ros.org/users/35598/spyros/) on 2018-10-23**:
I get: `Python 2.7.15` and:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named yaml
```

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-10-23**:
Can you run *any* ROS nodes? What does running `roscore` print fi? Does that also complain?

**Comment by [Spyros](https://answers.ros.org/users/35598/spyros/) on 2018-10-23**:
roscore looks working ok. But I get the same error when I try to run some other ROS nodes.

```
ImportError: No module named yaml
```

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-10-23**:
Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-yaml
```

then try this again:

```
/usr/bin/env python -c 'import yaml'
```

And for good measure: what is the output of:

```
which python
```

**Comment by [Spyros](https://answers.ros.org/users/35598/spyros/) on 2018-10-23**:
Reinstalletion worked ok, but after:

```
/usr/bin/env python -c 'import yaml'
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named yaml
```

which python gave me:

```
/usr/local/bin/python
```

Without restarting laptop or terminal.

**Comment by [Spyros](https://answers.ros.org/users/35598/spyros/) on 2018-10-23**:
@gvdhoorn  at least now I know where the problem comes from. Do you know how can I turn my python version from 2.7.15 into 2.7.12 or how to find the list of all modules required for ROS and the python version they use?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-10-23**:
It would probably be a good idea to first figure out *how* that additional Python version was installed, and *why*.

If you're not sure any more or are sure you don't need it any more, you could remove or rename the `python` binary from `/usr/local/bin`. That would probably result in the ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-10-23**:
.. system version being used again.

There are other alternatives, but they all involve work-arounds that are not very transparent or scalable (ie: `virtualenv`s, symlinks, etc).

As to a list of dependencies: I'm not aware of a single list of those.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-10-23**:
As a test to see whether things start working if you use the "correct" Python interpreter: replace the `#!/usr/bin/env python` line at the top of your script with:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

That should make it use the system provided Python and should tell you whether the installation is working ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-10-23**:
.. correctly.

Leaving the shebang like that is not advisable though, so this is not a solution.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-10-23**:
Finally: as your initial problem was solved (ie: you specified the wrong interpreter in your script) I would suggest to accept my answer by clicking on the checkmark (✓) to the left of the answer if you feel it has been answered.

**Comment by [Spyros](https://answers.ros.org/users/35598/spyros/) on 2018-10-23**:
Ok. I'll try to fix it using your advise. If I find any new or easier solution I'll put it as an answer. @gvdhoorn Thank you for your time!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-10-23**:
It seems your original question was already answered: you specified the wrong interpreter in the shebang.

The fact that you have a non-system-default Python installation in `/usr/local/bin` was not the cause. That is a different issue.